# The Travis CI build failed -Github

Tags: java, android, github

I pulled a request to a repository，but encountered a problem

> "continuous-integration/travis-ci/pr — > The Travis CI build failed"

after pulled the request. I have clicked *Detail* and read it, but I'm unable to locate the issue and don't know how to resolve it.
Please give me suggestions.
[image]

Comment: We have no access to your development environment, so you'll have to share what's in "Details" (and possibly relevant configs and codes). Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an automated build which is triggered when you create a pull request. Normally Travis will try and build your solution or run some form of testing against your changes.

My guess is that these automated builds or tests that are run through Travis have failed due to something you have changed.

You will need to go into Travis (A CI tool) and look at the build logs of that particular pull request and from there you will be able to see what has been failing.

Sorry that I couldn't be of more help but that is a very standard error message and further detail is needed :)

Comment: thanks a lot. i have read the log again and found the issue:)